# Need a help to active a hover effect on a menu when the user is in the page

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

So i have a website header menu, and a small css hover effect that changes the font color and creates a small green bar underneath the text, but i need this effect to stay on when the user is on the page associated to the "a" tag.

```
`<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/home"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/logo-header.png" class="logo-header" alt=""></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/barra-de-menu.png" class="menu" alt="" loading="lazy">
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <?php
                        function is_page_active($page_slug) {
                            global $post;
                            return is_page($page_slug) || (is_singular() && get_post_field('post_name', $post) === $page_slug);
                        }
                    ?>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item<?php echo is_page_active('home') ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
                            <a class="nav-link nav-efeito" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/home">Início</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item<?php echo is_page_active('sobre-nos') ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
                            <a class="nav-link nav-efeito" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/sobre-nos">Sobre</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item<?php echo is_page_active('empreendimentos') ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
                            <a class="nav-link nav-efeito" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/empreendimentos">Empreendimentos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item<?php echo is_page_active('blog') ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
                            <a class="nav-link nav-efeito" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/blog">Blog</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item<?php echo is_page_active('fale-conosco') ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
                            <a class="nav-link nav-efeito" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/fale-conosco">Contato</a>
                        </li>
                        <!-- <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link nav-efeito" href="/">Corretores</a>
                        </li> -->
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="centralizar-meio ms-auto m-0">
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/portal-do-cliente" class="btn-portalCliente">Portal do Cliente</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php the_field('link_area_do_cliente', 8) ?>" class="btn-areaCorretor">Área do Corretor</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/vamos-conversar" class="">
                                <div class="centralVendas">
                                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/fone-1.png" alt="" loading="lazy">
                                    <div class="infCentralVendas">
                                        <p class="textcentralVenda">CENTRAL DE VENDAS</p>
                                        <p class="foneCentralVendas"><?php the_field('telefone_central_de_vendas', 8) ?></p> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>`
```

Comment: You're missing a space after nav-item in `nav-item<?php echo is_page_active(...`

Comment: ... and the `active` class should be placed on the `<a class="nav-link ...`, not the `<li>` - all assuming you're using Bootstrap

Comment: The hover green effect does keep activated when that link is clicked.

Comment: i'm using Bootstrap. It should look like this? <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link nav-efeito<?php echo is_page_active('home') ? 'active' : ''; ?>" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/home">Início</a>
                        </li>

Comment: Great. Still missing the space

Comment: Fixed, now should i do any CSS fixes? 

.nav-link {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.nav-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
header .nav-efeito{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}
.nav-efeito::after {
  content: '';
  height: 6px;
  width: 0;
  background: #83C340;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  transition: all .25s;
}
.nav-efeito:hover::after {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}

Comment: _"Fixed, now should i do any CSS fixes?"_ - you set the class `active` on the element - so now your CSS must also contain rule(s) that apply based on the element having that class, yes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to add an "active" class to the `<li>` element when the associated page is active.

The problem might have been due to the absence of a space before the "active" class in your code. Ensure proper spacing by adding a space before the "active" class in the `<li>` elements, as demonstrated in the provided code snippets.

```
<li class="nav-item <?php echo is_page_active('home') ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
    <a class="nav-link nav-efeito" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/home">Início</a>
</li>
```